# MKAnnotationView not Removing from MKMapView

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I have a simple array or MKAnnotations for location objects that are fetched from CoreData upon view load. When I remove a location object, I also manually remove the location object from the array. After removing from array I call removeAnnotations() and then addAnnotations() based on the array. I notice that the MKAnnotationView is no longer at the removed location, however it is not removed from the MapView only moved to 0º lat 0º lon.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong in order to get it to completely remove from the MapView.

*** Note: I am following a tutorial, and for learning processes I am manually updating the locations array instead of using NSFetchedResultsController.

Thoughts?

Here is the code:

```
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext! {
    didSet {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification, object: managedObjectContext, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { notification in
            if self.isViewLoaded() {
                if let dictionary = notification.userInfo {

                    if dictionary["inserted"] != nil {

                        print("*** Inserted")
                        let insertedLocationSet: NSSet = dictionary["inserted"] as! NSSet
                        let insertedLocationArray: NSArray = insertedLocationSet.allObjects
                        let insertedLocation = insertedLocationArray[0] as! Location
                        self.locations.append(insertedLocation)

                    } else if dictionary["deleted"] != nil {

                        print("*** Deleted")
                        let deletedLocationSet = dictionary["deleted"] as! NSSet
                        let deletedLocationArray = deletedLocationSet.allObjects
                        let deletedLocation = deletedLocationArray[0] as! Location

                        if let objectIndexInLocations = self.locations.indexOf(deletedLocation) {

                            self.locations.removeAtIndex(objectIndexInLocations)

                        }

                    }
                }
            }

            self.drawAnnotations()

        }
    }
}

var locations = [Location]()


func updateLocations() {  // called by viewDidLoad()

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Location", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.entity = entity

    locations = try! managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Location]

    drawAnnotations()

}

func drawAnnotations() {

    mapView.removeAnnotations(locations)
    mapView.addAnnotations(locations)

}
```

Comment: Can you show the `drawAnnotations()` method? Are you calling `removeAnnotation(:)` method on your map view anywhere in your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that when you execute `mapView.removeAnnotations(locations)` the `locations` array has already been updated and the deleted annotation is no longer in that array, so it isn't removed.  You can remove all current annotations by referring to the `annotations` property on the MapView itself -

```
func drawAnnotations() {
    mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
    mapView.addAnnotations(locations) 
}
```